# Virtualenv python entre máquinas Win/Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, virtualenv

tenho um problema, alguém ja passou por isso ?

Tenho um projeto Python/Django em um pc linux, e esse projeto esta num repositorio no github.

Dei git clone nesse repositorio em outro pc windows, até ai tudo bem, agora eu tento instalar qualquer coisa com pip install e a venv ativa ele da erro.

O problema é com a virtual env do projeto do repositorio, pois pra testar, nesse pc windows criei uma nova venv, ativei ela e funciona normalmente
Observe a venv ( teste) esta foi criada no proprio pc windows para teste, funciona normal
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esta é a venv da pasta do projeto la do github, essa venv foi criada em outro pc
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é o erro que dá
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém pode me ajudar a entender qual é o problema? e como posso fazer pra evitar que aconteça, de forma que eu consiga trabalhar em multiplas maquinas no mesmo projeto.

Answer (score 2):

O "virtualenv" não deve ser incluso nos arquivos versionados pelo GIT.
As bibliotecas e módulos que são instaladas para um projeto funcionar no virtualenv são sempre dependentes do sistema operacional e arquitetura onde o projeto está rodando.

O correto é excluir a pasta do virtualenv do git - e, em cada computador onde você baixar o projeto, criar um virtualenv específico pra aquele computador (e inclsuive, para aquela pasta onde você clonou o projeto, se clonar mais de um lugar).

Se o projeto estiver configurado direito, um "pip install ." ou "python setup.py develop" vão instalar as dependencias na máquina destino.

Comment: No caso quando eu for subir um projeto Django no github, o ideal é só subir a pasta "Script" que é onde vai estar os arquivos do Django?

Comment: voc precisa dos arquivos que o django cria, quando voce roda o "manage startproject" - e precisa ver doc. em paralelo sobre como transformar o projeto django em um projeto Python - com setup.py _ou_ usar o "poetry" e ter o "pyproject.toml".  Mas nada do virtualenv

Comment: putz, eu sempre criava uma venv e nesse mesmo diretório criava o remote do github e subia a venv inteira pro github, por isso volta e meia tinha esses problemas. Obrigado por responder mesmo minha pergunta estando toda bagunçada.

Comment: não - são conceitos complementare, praticamente "feitos" pra funcionarem os dois, mas sem se misturarem: controle de versão (git),garante que os arquivos que são únicos para seu projeto funcionar (o código fonte) sejam iguais em qualquer computador. Gerenciamento de pacotes por ambinte (venv) garante que em cada instalação, os requisitos apropriados pro funcionamento do projeto sejam instalados para a arquiteteura e S.O. específicos (e seu projeto seja "buildado" se houver esse passo), da forma mais automática possível .